# How to integrate sagaMiddleWare.run(RootSaga) into a redux storeFactory

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, redux-saga

The code below is a store factory which will create a store on command given the statement

```
const store = storeFactory()
```

I need to integrate sagaMiddleWare with this storeFactory but any place that I put the code:

`sagaMiddleWare.run(RootSaga)`

I receive the error:

Error: Before running a Saga, you must mount the Saga middleware on the Store using applyMiddleware

How can I integrate the `sagaMiddleWare.run(RootSaga)` into the storeFactory ?

```
"use strict";

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { user, venues, isFetching } from "./reducers";
import stateData from "./initialState.json";
import RootSaga from "./sagas";

const logger = store => next => action => {
  let result;
  console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type);
  console.log("prev state", store.getState());
  console.log("action", action);
  result = next(action);
  console.log("next state", store.getState());
  console.groupEnd();
  return result;
};

const saver = store => next => action => {
  let result = next(action);
  localStorage["redux-store"] = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
  return result;
};

const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware();

const storeFactory = (initialState = stateData) =>
  applyMiddleware(logger, saver, sagaMiddleWare)(createStore)(
    combineReducers({ user, venues, isFetching }),
    localStorage["redux-store"]
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage["redux-store"])
      : stateData
  );

export default storeFactory;
```

Comment: Try placing `combineReducers` before `applyMiddleware`

Answer (score 0):

Here getting an error which seems to indicate that the saga middleware is not getting loaded properly with the store.

```
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ || compose;
    const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
      );
    sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
/* eslint-enable */

The final code of this tutorial is located in the sagas branch. Then in the .... Now we only have to invoke sagaMiddleware.run on the root Saga in main.js .
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html
```